# Menu strip of parented process not working

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have created a application in vb.net 2017. I am parenting another application made in vb.net 2017 to my main application's tab control.
When I am parenting notepad I can access its menu. But when I am parenting self made vb.net another application, Menu is showing but drop down is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the AllowDrop property of ContextMenuStrip to True

Comment: I dont have ContextMenuStrip but menustrip. I set the allowdrop property of this control to true. But did not work. I then did it for form itself, and then for master form also but nothing worked.